# Put some shiny code in another file and import it in server.R ou ui.R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to know how to import code in the server.R part. I have a button.R file with an observeEvent. When I import it into the server.R file with the source() function, I get an error when I run my application.

**app.R**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"), dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Accueil", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                                 actionButton("button", "button"),
                                 ))))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  source(file = "button.R")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**button.R**

```
observeEvent(input$button, {
  print("clicked")
})
```

**Error**

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5919
Warning: Error in eval_tidy: object 'input' not found
  1: runApp
```

Comment: If you put the code into a subdirectory called `R` it will be sourced automatically by Shiny. Alternatively, you can use a framework like ‘golem’ which allows you to properly modularise your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making wrapping the content of `button.R` in a function which is passed `input` and calling that in the server:

```
my_button <- function(input){
observeEvent(input$button, {
  print("clicked")
})
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  source(file = "button.R")
  my_button(input)
}
```